# How to update 2d-shader coordinates when camera moves

Tags: python

I'm drawing some lines using a `2D_UNIFORM_COLOR` shader based on object location. When I rotate my view, the lines update only when the rotation is done: I thought that I can just put a function that updates my coordinates in `modal()` but this didn't work. So I wonder if there's a way to update the regions while the view is rotated?

[image]

P.S. I realise that a 3d shader would work better for drawing axes, but axes here is just an example

My code:

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
import bgl
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d

def draw_callback_px(self, context):

    # do I really have to create a separate shader for each line? Ugh

    shader_X = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
    shader_Y = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
    shader_Z = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glLineWidth(2)
    
    v_x = (self.axes[0] - self.ob_location).normalized()
    v_y = (self.axes[1] - self.ob_location).normalized()
    v_z = (self.axes[2] - self.ob_location).normalized()
    batch_X = batch_for_shader(shader_X, 'LINE_STRIP', {"pos": [self.ob_location, self.ob_location + v_x*100]})
    batch_Y = batch_for_shader(shader_Y, 'LINE_STRIP', {"pos": [self.ob_location, self.ob_location + v_y*100]})
    batch_Z = batch_for_shader(shader_Z, 'LINE_STRIP', {"pos": [self.ob_location, self.ob_location + v_z*100]})

    shader_X.bind()
    shader_X.uniform_float("color", (1, 0, 0, 0.2))
    batch_X.draw(shader_X)

    shader_Y.bind()
    shader_Y.uniform_float("color", (0, 1, 0, 0.2))
    batch_Y.draw(shader_Y)

    shader_Z.bind()
    shader_Z.uniform_float("color", (0, 0, 1, 0.2))
    batch_Z.draw(shader_Z)

    # restore opengl defaults
    bgl.glLineWidth(1)
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_BLEND)

class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move an object with the mouse, example"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator_test"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator Test"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        
        self.update_region(context, event)
        
        # Navigation
        if event.type in {'MIDDLEMOUSE', 'WHEELUPMOUSE', 'WHEELDOWNMOUSE'} or event.alt:        
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.ob = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
        if not self.ob:
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        self.update_region(context, event)

        args = (self, context)
        self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    
    def update_region(self, context, event):
        self.region = context.region
        self.rv3d = context.space_data.region_3d
        self.ob_location = location_3d_to_region_2d(self.region, self.rv3d, self.ob.location, default=None)
        self.axes = [location_3d_to_region_2d(self.region, self.rv3d, self.ob.location + Vector((1,0,0)), default=None),
                     location_3d_to_region_2d(self.region, self.rv3d, self.ob.location + Vector((0,1,0)), default=None),
                     location_3d_to_region_2d(self.region, self.rv3d, self.ob.location + Vector((0,0,1)), default=None)]
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: as I wrote all that is below, I just realized the question was explicitly about 2D shader...

You just missed to call

```
self.update_region(context, None)
```

from **inside the callback**, which is itself called at each drawing.

Though, as it is the calculation is not correct. You should use object world matrix (see the previous answer).

---

Previous answer (I don't delete it as that could be useful):

As you want to move during the operator, you are in 3d, use:

```
gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
```

instead of:

```
gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
```

Also, in this case, use `POST_VIEW`, as indicated in [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Space.html?highlight=draw_handler_add#bpy.types.Space.draw_handler_add).

> draw_type (str) – Usually POST_PIXEL for 2D drawing and POST_VIEW for
> 3D drawing. In some cases PRE_VIEW can be used. BACKDROP can be used
> for backdrops in the node editor.

```
self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

One shader is needed.

You can start from object axis and convert them in world space:

```
def draw_callback_px(self, context):

    obj = context.active_object
    mat = obj.matrix_world

    shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
    shader.bind()

    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glLineWidth(2)

    origin = mat @ Vector((0, 0, 0)) #Convert coordinates in world space
    x = mat @ Vector((2,0,0))
    y = mat @ Vector((0,2,0))
    z = mat @ Vector((0,0,2))
    batch_X = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": [origin, x]}, indices = ((0, 1),) )
    batch_Y = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": [origin, y]}, indices = ((0, 1),) )
    batch_Z = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": [origin, z]}, indices = ((0, 1),) )

    shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 0, 0, 0.2))
    batch_X.draw(shader)

    shader.uniform_float("color", (0, 1, 0, 0.2))
    batch_Y.draw(shader)

    shader.uniform_float("color", (0, 0, 1, 0.2))
    batch_Z.draw(shader)

    # restore opengl defaults
    bgl.glLineWidth(1)
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why `POST_VIEW`?

Comment: @brockmann, just edited about that. I don't know why, but it is in the docs...

Comment: Cool! Thanks @lemon.

Comment: @brockmann... fyi (if needed), the issue was simply... see edited answer... : ))

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I knew how to make it work for 3d shader so I was looking for a solution for 2d shader. Putting my region_update to draw callback fixed the issue I had, thank you!